# Why is that sometimes I hear kudasai (with d) pronounced as kurasai (a slight r sound)?

Tags: pitch-accent

Here's an example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMgXlcgj8Y8&t=61s

I'm a Chilean-born Taiwanese, so I'm not sure if my ears are confusing things. Or maybe this is due different Japanese accents?

Or maybe the Japanese "d" is a blit "r" sounding?

Comment: Latin orthography can be confusing here. The consonant of the ら-row sounds somewhat like US-English [「be**tt**er」](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/En-us-better.ogg).

Comment: @droooze Oh, so I was right. There's a slight "r" sound?

Comment: Look at it from the point of view of real phonology (e.g. via IPA) rather than *romaji*. 「ら」is transcribed as [**ɾ**a̠], while US/Canadian English「be**tt**er」is transcribed as [ˈbɛ**ɾ**ɚ].「ɾ」is the [dental, alveolar, and post-alveolar flap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_and_alveolar_flaps). Describing it as an "r" sound means different things to different people who pronounce "r" differently (not withstanding that "r" sounds incredibly different depending on what word it is spelt with; seriously sound out all the "r"s in these comments and you'll see this).

Comment: Explicitly, if you associate the consonant in the だ-row as something like English "t/d", then you may further associate だ with an "r" sound because English "t/d" is associated with the consonant in the ら-row, which is transcribed in *romaji* as *r-*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been pronounced "kudasai" and not "kurasai", focus and listen to it again.